# PassportJS cookie based auth integrated with React Native app

Tags: react-native, expo, passport.js

I have a web app which is build with Node, Express & PassportJS. This app is used with my web client to authenticate users and communicate with DB.

I'm now building a React Native app which will act as an alternative to the web client. I would like to use the same service as I'm using on the web client but I'm running in to a couple of issues.

The flow I want to implement in React native is something like:

1. User interacts with Google login button.
2. WebView is opened with the Google login screen.
3. User Signs in and is redirected back to app.
4. Cookie token is picked out from response header and used for following requests.

Doing #1 and #2 is pretty straight forward.
The issue is that my passport service just redirects to '/' after logging in and the web client is displayed. Here is where I want to redirect back to Native app and bringing the cookie sent from passportJS with it. Is there a "simple" solution for this or is it not viable to use this kind of authentication with a Native app?

NOTE: I'm using Expo for the React Native app.

Comment: i have same problem ,Have you found the solution?